# select which album to display Jquery Masonry

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

i am beginer to wp and Php.
I am using Jquery Masonry image gallery to present some photo albums. 
The problem i have is that i dont know how to only show the selected albums.Here is a picture:

http://imageshack.com/a/img163/4227/lojs.jpg

there are two categorys: Tous les reportage and toutes les parutions.
Baisicly i want the "tous les reportages" page to show only the 3 reportages and not the other albums.

I hope someone can guide me. I searched the forums but couldn't find anything...

Comment: show your db schema. have a album table which has id photoid
photo table has id url heading etc.

Comment: This question belongs on wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you for your answer, What do you mean with db schema?